# jquery How to loop through a series of items and take action?

Tags: jquery

Given HTML like:

```
<div class="itemList">
  <div class="streamBox version-2"> stuff </div>
  <div class="streamBox version-2"> stuff </div>
  <div class="streamBox version-3"> stuff </div>
  <div class="streamBox version-2"> stuff </div>
  <div class="streamBox version-3"> stuff </div>
  <div class="streamBox version-1"> stuff </div>
</div>
```

How can I get jquery to loop through all the '.streamBox' inside of the '.itemList' div?

When looping through, given a version #, like 2, how to get it to show() version-2 but hide all the others?

Thanks

Comment: You know about the UL element, right?

Comment: why do you need to loop if all you want to do is show an specific version number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.itemList').children('.steamBox').each(function(index) {
    // Now you can use $(this) to manipulate a list item
    if (index != 2) // index starts at 0
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Don't use the name `id` for the iterator variable, since `id` already is the name of the ID property on elements.

Comment: Really? Do you have a reference? To me it seems like id is undefined pretty much always when I debug if I haven't declared it myself. However, index or i is a better name.

Comment: Sure: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037 Every DOM element contains the `id` property which value is based on the ID attribute in th HTML source code.

Comment: Yes it's undefined if not explicitly set. What I mean is the the name `id` should not be used for an iterator. In your code above, one might wrongfully conclude that the `id` argument contains the `id` property of the current element.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.itemList').children().hide().filter('.version-2').show();
```

---

Also, use the UL element:

```
<ul class="itemList">
  <li class="version-2"> stuff </li>
  <li class="version-2"> stuff </li>
  <li class="version-3"> stuff </li>
  <li class="version-2"> stuff </li>
  <li class="version-3"> stuff </li>
  <li class="version-1"> stuff </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why use UL and LIs?

Comment: @AnApprentice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057913/using-ul-in-place-of-divs-recommended-where-to-use-1-or-the-other

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
function showVersion(ver) {
$('.streamBox').hide();
$('.version-' + ver).show();
}
```

Comment: Those selectors are inefficient

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid, bec there is no reason to hide everything

Comment: `$('.streamBox')` will search on the entire page. If the page has hundreds or even thousands of elements, then this selector query is considerably slower than it should be. You want to make your selectors as specific as possible. For instance: `$('.streamBox', 'ul.itemList')`. Also, the second query will again search on the entire page. But in this case, it is even more pointless, since you already grabbed the elements in the previous query. You just have to filter out the ones that you need: `$('.streamBox').hide().filter('.version-2').show();`

Comment: Ok. I agree. I guess i was just referencing the snippet included. Itis just the 2nd selector that causes the inefficiency.